# Lost Power during Krita installation from terminal. Now cannot install anything because of dpkg error

Tags: dpkg

```
    eric@Eric-PC:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
eric@Eric-PC:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,340 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ntrack-module-libnl-0:
 ntrack-module-libnl-0 depends on libntrack0 (>= 005); however:
  Package libntrack0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ntrack-module-libnl-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package libntrack0 (--configure):
 package libntrack0 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 ntrack-module-libnl-0
 libntrack0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried fixing things by myself when I tried to delete `ntrack-module-libnl-0` and `libntrack0` and then re-installing it. But that's not working. I am regretting trying to fix without consulting here so I do not want to do anything else without knowing how to fix this.

This is the following out from `sudo apt install -f` :

```
eric@Eric-PC:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,340 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ntrack-module-libnl-0:
 ntrack-module-libnl-0 depends on libntrack0 (>= 005); however:
  Package libntrack0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ntrack-module-libnl-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package libntrack0 (--configure):
 package libntrack0 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 ntrack-module-libnl-0
 libntrack0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please try to run `sudo apt install -f`and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from the half installed packages post
Just had to reinstall the packages using the following command:

`sudo apt install --reinstall <package name>`

Thanks for the help guys.